# c++ soap client

Tags: php, c++, magento

Is there something similar to PHP's SoapClient class for c++? I am working on converting set of php scripts for the magento API. I'm processing a ton of xml data and I want it to run faster.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).  It's a pretty decent SOAP framework for C and C++

Apache also have a C++ implementation of [Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/index.html)

gSoap seems to be more mature than Axis C++, however the gSoap API is C, not C++, so if you need a native C++ API then Axis C++ would be the way to go.  Writing a C++ wrapper for the gSoap API would be fairly trivial though